# SSRS Report Builder parameters

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have following problem using report builder in Visual Studio 2015:
When I try to add date parameter (BETWEEN statement) into following code VS automatically changes them to question marks eg. @Datefrom -> '?'

```
SELECT DISTINCT au.FIRST_NAME AS 'Serwisant',
(SELECT COUNT(CHARGEID) AS Expr1
 FROM ChargesTable AS ct
 WHERE (TECHNICIANID = hdc.TECHNICIANID) 
 AND (DATEADD(s, DATEDIFF(s, GETUTCDATE(), GETDATE()) + TS_STARTTIME / 1000, '1970-01-01 00:00:00') BETWEEN DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)  AND DATEADD(s, - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) ) 
 AND (CHARGEID IN (SELECT CHARGEID
                   FROM WorkOrderToCharge) 
 OR CHARGEID IN (SELECT CHARGEID
                 FROM TaskToCharge 
                 WHERE (TASKID IN
                       (SELECT TASKID
                        FROM WorkOrderToTaskDetails))))) AS 'Ilosc wpisow'
FROM HelpDeskCrew AS hdc INNER JOIN
 AaaUser AS au ON au.USER_ID = hdc.TECHNICIANID
```

My code has like 3 or 4 simillar blocks with 'between' statements and when i change them to parameters the VS changes all of them to '?' and gives me 10 werid parameter in report designers.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to do a report, where user would enter StartDate and EndDate parameters.

Assuming you have a Data Source, to achieve this you need to create a Data Set based on your query, like this:

```
SELECT BirthDate 
FROM DimCustomer 
WHERE BirthDate > @StartDate AND BirthDate < @EndDate
```

This will automatically create two parameters @StartDate and @EndDate. You may want to change this parameters to accept only datetime values.